# Match ids to a given set of ids in a group by statement in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a simple table that tracks if a user has submitted a specific activity.

| user_id | activity_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 |
| 1 | 222 |
| 1 | 333 |
| 1 | 444 |
| 2 | 111 |
| 2 | 222 |
| 3 | 111 |
| 3 | 222 |
| 3 | 333 |
| 5 | 777 |
| 5 | 111 |

I want to write SQL that will group by `user_id` and given a list that I already have, would return true if the group `activity_id` has all `activity_id` in the list. Pretty much a check to see if the user has submitted a set of `activity_id`

So after the SQL the table would look something like this if I used this list of ids to check `(111,222,333)`

| user_id | submitted_minimum_activities |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | true |
| 2 | false |
| 3 | true |
| 5 | false |

Note it doesnt have to be an exact match, I just want to check if the user has at least submitted all the activities in the list. `user_id=1` also submitted `activity_id=444` (not in the given list) but still returned true because they submitted all the activities in the list.

Im using BigQuery.

EDIT:
Using a `WHERE` clause isn't possible. The original table is already doing other calculations and I cant limit it to just the list of activity IDs

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user_id,
  CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT activity_id) >= 3 THEN true ELSE false END AS submitted_minimum_activities
FROM your_table_name
WHERE activity_id IN (111, 222, 333) -- replace with your list of activity_ids
GROUP BY user_id
```

- filter the table to only include rows where the activity_id is in the given list
- group by user_id
- `CASE` to check if the count of distinct activity_ids is at least 3 (which is the length of the given list)(it is -- we return true -- else we return false)